# Change the drop down list one another dynamically

Tags: jsp

In `cityPair.jsp` i am displaying 3 values  `Air`,`Rail`,`Bus` as drop down in Travel Mode Field and Beside this field displaying 3 values `First Class`, `Business Class`, `Economy Class` as drop down in `Fare Class` filed

Now on selection of `Rail` the The `Fare Class` values should be changed to `First Class` `AC`, `Sleeper Class`.

Travel Mode Div section:

```
<div class="grid_2 omega  trip_city_pair">
        <my:select optionCode="value" selectOptionPath="${modeOfTravel}"
            required="true" optionLabel="label" label="mode"
            path="tripDetail.cityPairs[${index}].travelMode" index="${index}" onchange="onSelectionChange(${index})"></my:select>
</div>
```

Fare Class Div Section:

```
<div class="grid_4  trip_city_pair">
<my:select optionCode="id"  selectOptionPath="${fareClass}" required="true" optionLabel="i18nTextName.defaultText" label="fareClass" cssStyle="width: 150px;"
path="tripDetail.cityPairs[${index}].fareClass" index="${index}"></my:select>       
</div>
```

`${fareClass}`--->This is the object am mapping from the controller which contains the following values
Business Class, 
Economy Class

`${railFareClass}`-->This is the object am mapping from the controller which contains the following values
First Class AC,
Sleeper Class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem you are facing ?

Comment: use jquery for dynamic changing values of select box.